# Custom Post Type Loop throws 500 error when used in widget

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop, widgets, genesis-theme-framework

I'm trying to add a custom post type custom loop in a widget.

Everything here worked correctly until I added the loop to the `our_team_section_after()` function.

I can't find any syntax errors, however, Whenever I add the loop I get a 500 internal server error. When I take it back out, it works fine.

I'm using the Genesis Framework, so some of the hooks are genesis exclusive.

I've really been searching the web for an answer and I've returned no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
//Register the widget areas
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'landing-section',
'name' => __( 'Landing Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'First Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'who-we-are-section',
'name' => __( 'Who We Are Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Who We Are Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'creative-process-section',
'name' => __( 'Creative Process Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Creative Process Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'services-section',
'name' => __( 'Services Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Services Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'our-team-section',
'name' => __( 'Our Team Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Our Team Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'case-studies-section',
'name' => __( 'Case Studies Section', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Case Studies Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id' => 'worked-with-section',
'name' => __( 'Who We\'ve Worked With', 'genesis' ),
'description' => __( 'Who We\'ve Worked With Homepage Section.', 'Bootstrap Genesis' ),
) );


//* Add the page widget in the content - XHTML
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'front_page_content' );
function front_page_content() {
if ( is_front_page() ){
    genesis_widget_area ('landing-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="landing-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('who-we-are-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="who-we-are-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('creative-process-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="creative-process-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('services-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="services-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('our-team-section', array(
        'before' => our_team_section_before(),
        'after' => our_team_section_after(),
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('case-studies-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="case-studies-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
    genesis_widget_area ('worked-with-section', array(
        'before' => '<div id="worked-with-section"><div class="container">',
        'after' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
}
}

function our_team_section_before() {
$before = '<div id="our-team-section">';
$before .= '<div class="container">';

return $before;
}

function our_team_section_after() {
$after = '</div>';
    $after .= '<div class="container-fluid">';
        $after .= '<div class="row">';
            $after .= '<div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">';
                $after .= '<div class="owl-carousel">';

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'team_post_type'
                    );
                    $query = new WP_Query($args);

                    if( $query -> have_posts() ){
                        $query -> while( have_posts() ){
                            $query -> the_post();
                            $after .= '<div>';
                            $after .= the_post_thumbnail();
                            $after .= '</div>';
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }

                $after .= '</div>';
            $after .= '</div>';
            $after .= '<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">';
                $after .= '<div class="homepage-cta">';
                    $after .= '<span>See Entire Team &gt;</span>';
                $after .= '</div>';
            $after .= '</div>';
        $after .= '</div>';
    $after .= '</div>';
$after .= '</div>';

return $after;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please elaborate your problem. I don't see the question here.

Comment: @JackJohansson Sorry about that! Better?

Comment: You can't use `the_post_thumbnail` in assignment (or any WP functions that start with `the_`), you need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail`.

Comment: Yes that is. I am unfamiliar with the `$query -> while( have_posts() )`. Did you mean `while($query->have_posts());`? Also you should move your `wp_reset_postdata()` out of the conditional. `the_post_thumbnail()` will echo the content, while you need to return it. So as Milo mentioned, you should use `get_the...` instead.

Comment: I made both those edits, and I got it working. I'm pretty sure the 500 error was from @JackJohansson 's edit that I missed. Thank you!

Comment: @JRobz You're welcome! I'll post a more detailed answer explaining the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your provided code.

### `$query -> while( have_posts() )`

The [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) return type is object. You are referring to a method that doesn't exist. Instead, you should use the following:

```
while( $query->have_posts() ) {...}
```

### `wp_reset_postdata();` inside the conditional

This function resets the post's data, as it suggests. If you use it inside a conditional, and the conditional doesn't run, your post's data won't be reset, leaving an empty query active. So, you should use it outside the conditional, or before `return`, if you are returning the data instead.

### `the_...` instead of `get_the_...`

If you want to store the data in a variable, you should use a function that returns the data, not echo it. `the_post_thumbanil()` echoes the thumbnail, while you need to return it. So, you should use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead. This applies to every WordPress function that begins with `the_...`, as far as i know.